# What do I need for this generic Constructor to work?

Tags: java, generics

So i'm trying to make a maze with generic classes and interfaces and Im not quite sure where i've gone wrong. My main problem is how to complete my constructor because its the first time I have a class as a parameter.

This is my first post so I apologies if it's bad.

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Labyrinth implements ILabyrinth {
    private int height;
    private int width;

    **********************************************
    public Labyrinth(IGrid<LabyrinthTile> tiles){
        tiles.copy();
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;       <---Here?
    **********************************************  

    }

    @Override
    public LabyrinthTile getCell(int x, int y) {

        return getCell(x,y);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor(int x, int y) {

        return getCell(x,y).getColor();
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {

        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPlayerGold() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPlayerHitPoints() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {

        return width;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void movePlayer(Direction dir) throws MovePlayerException {

        if(dir.equals(Direction.EAST)){
            width+=1;
        }
        if(dir.equals(Direction.NORTH)){
            height+=1;
        }
        if(dir.equals(Direction.SOUTH)){
            height-=1;
        }
        if(dir.equals(Direction.WEST)){
            width-=1;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean playerCanGo(Direction d) {
        if(d.equals(LabyrinthTile.WALL))
            return false;
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: What does `tiles.copy()` do, return a copy of tiles? In that case you didn't store it anywhere.

Comment: Yes exactly where should i store it?

Comment: I don't know, where do you need a copy of tiles? Or do you just need some data from tiles, in this case you don't need a copy.

Comment: I'm supposed to use the copy(); to protect the inclosed data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type the following:

```
this.height = height;
```

You are saying that you want to set the "height" field of the new object you're trying to create to a variable called "height." But your constructor doesn't have a variable named "height" anywhere in the constructor or as one of the constructor's arguments. You want something like the following:

```
// .height() might not be a real method, it's just an example 
this.height = tiles.height();
```

That will work because you have a variable named "tiles" passed into the constructor.

Comment: Had to change it to getHeight(); tho

Comment: Yep, I said in the comment that .height() might not be a real method. In Java, if you want to get the property of something (like the height or width), usually you'd do it through the use of a "getter," hence, "getHeight()."

Comment: Yeah that's true, hmm i seem to get a bunch of other errors when i run the application now. In the getCell method. It seems to be a infinite loop of errors hehe.